# Match a string that contains a newline using sed

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have a string like this one:

```
    #
    pap
```

which basically translates to a `\t#\n\tpap` and I want to replace it with:

```
    #
    pap
    python
```

which translates to `\t#\n\tpap\n\tpython`.

Tried this with `sed` in a lot of ways but it's not working maybe because `sed` uses new lines in a different way. I tried with:

```
sed -i "s/\t#\n\tpap/\t#\tpython\n\tpap/" /etc/freeradius/sites-available/default
```

...and many different other ways with no result. Any idea how can I do my replace in this situation?

Comment: sed is an excellent tool for simple substitution son a single line. It is NOT to be used on any problem that involves matching REs across multiple lines. The sed language constructs for that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Comment: stick `/^\t#/N;` at the front of yours, it'll work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this line with gawk:

```
awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="" '{gsub(/\t#\n\tpap/,"yourNEwString")}7' file
```

if you want to let `sed`  handle new lines, you have to read the whole file first:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\t#\n\tpap/NewString/g' file
```

Comment: Here's sed without reading the whole file first: `sed  -e ':b; /^\t#$/ { N; s/\n\tpap$/&\n\tpython/; te; P; D; }; :e'`

Comment: +` for the awk solution. I'm ignoring the sed one so I can +1 the awk one :-). BTW I recently discovered that there are people parsing text files that contain `NUL` chars and so using `RS='\0'` doesn't work for them so I've switched to by default using `RS='^$'` and stating it's gawk-only. `^$` works because those 2 chars match the start and end of a string, and gawk treats an input file as a string to be split into records so `RS='^$'` is only true for an empty string/file and cannot exist in a file with any content. If they can't get gawk, then `RS='\0'` is next with the caveat I mentioned.

Comment: What is the `7` for after the end of the `gsub`?

Comment: @LironYahdav `print`

Comment: Unfortunately no explation to why this works better.

Comment: @trapicki don't get you, don't understand the downvote either

Comment: The answer seems to work, but I do not understand why this works, what it does in detail. An explanation of your solution would increase my knowledge. This way I can only copy the solution and still have the problem with the next challenge.

Comment: @trapicki OP has written sed codes in his/her question, I assume that OP can understand what I wrote in my answer. No matter awk or sed, you need to know what basic command means, like N, s/.../../ , ba etc. those explanations are in sed's man page, same situation for awk. I don't have to repeat the thing in man page here once again.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\t#$/{n;/^\tpap$/{p;s//\tpython/}}' file
```

If a line contains only `\t#` print it, then if the next line contains only `\tpap` print it too, then replace that line with `\tpython` and print that.

Comment: +1 - clever. Was puzzled by the `p` at first, given that `n` normally prints the newly loaded line, until I realized that your `s` command effectively the deletes the line by not referring to it in the replacement string; in other words: `p;s//\typthon/` is the equivalent of: `s//&\n\tpython/`.

Answer (score 4):

A **GNU `sed`** solution that *doesn't require reading the entire file at once*:

```
sed '/^\t#$/ {n;/^\tpap$/a\\tpython'$'\n''}' file
```

- `/^\t#$/` matches comment-only lines (matching `\t#` exactly), in which case (only) the entire `{...}` expression is executed:

  - `n` loads and prints the *next* line.
  - `/^\tpap/` matches that next line against `\tpap` exactly.
  - in case of a match, `a\\tpython` will then output `\n\tpython` before the *following* line is read - note that the spliced-in newline (`$'\n'`) is required to signal the end of the text passed to the `a` command (you can alternatively use multiple `-e` options).

(As an aside: with **BSD `sed` (OS X)**, it gets cumbersome, because

- Control chars. such as `\n` and `\t` aren't directly supported and must be spliced in as ANSI C-quoted literals.
- Leading whitespace is invariably stripped from the text argument to the `a` command, so a substitution approach must be used: `s//&\'$'\n\t'python'/` replaces the `pap` line with itself *plus* the line to append:

  ```
  sed '/^'$'\t''#$/ {n; /^'$'\t''pap$/ s//&\'$'\n\t'python'/;}' file
  ```

)

---

An **`awk` solution** (POSIX-compliant) that also *doesn't require reading the entire file at once*:

```
awk '{print} /^\t#$/ {f=1;next} f && /^\tpap$/ {print "\tpython"} {f=0}' file
```

- `{print}`: prints every input line
- `/^\t#$/ {f=1;next}`: sets flag `f` (for 'found') to `1` if a comment-only line (matching `\t#` exactly) is found and moves on to the next line.
- `f && /^\tpap$/ {print "\tpython"}`: if a line is preceded by a comment line and matches `\tpap` exactly, outputs extra line `\tpython`.
- `{f=0}`: resets the flag that indicates a comment-only line.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of pure `bash` solutions:

#### Concise, but somewhat fragile, using parameter expansion:

```
in=$'\t#\n\tpap\n' # input string

echo "${in/$'\t#\n\tpap\n'/$'\t#\n\tpap\n\tpython\n'}"
```

- Parameter expansion only supports *patterns* (wildcard expressions) as search strings, which limits the matching abilities:
- Here the assumption is made that `pap` is followed by `\n`, whereas no assumption is made about what precedes `\t#`, potentially resulting in false positives.
- If the assumption could be made that `\t#\n\tpap` is always *enclosed* in `\n`, `echo "${in/$'\n\t#\n\tpap\n'/$'\n\t#\n\tpap\n\tpython\n'}"` would work robustly; otherwise, see below.

#### Robust, but verbose, using the `=~` operator for regex matching:

The `=~` operator supports *extended regular expressions* on the right-hand side and thus allows more flexible and robust matching:

```
in=$'\t#\n\tpap' # input string 

# Search string and string to append after.
search=$'\t#\n\tpap'
append=$'\n\tpython'

out=$in # Initialize output string to input string.
if [[ $in =~ ^(.*$'\n')?("$search")($'\n'.*)?$ ]]; then # perform regex matching
    out=${out/$search/$search$append} # replace match with match + appendage
fi

echo "$out"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just translate the character \n to another one, then apply `sed`, then apply the reverse translation. If `tr` is used, it must be a 1-byte character, for instance \v (vertical tabulation, nowadays almost unused).

```bash
cat FILE|tr '\n' '\v'|sed 's/\t#\v\tpap/&\v\tpython/'|tr '\v' '\n'|sponge FILE
```

or, without sponge:

```bash
cat FILE|tr '\n' '\v'|sed 's/\t#\v\tpap/&\v\tpython/'|tr '\v' '\n' >FILE.bak && mv FILE.bak FILE
```