# sed to match pattern across a newline

Tags: regex, xml, bash, awk, sed

Here's my input:

```
<array>
    <string>extra1</string>
    <string>extra2</string>
    <string>Yellow
5</string>
```

Note: there's a space and newline between "Yellow" and "5"

I am piping this to sed:

```
| sed -n 's#.*<string>\(.*\)</string>#\1#p'
```

and I am getting the output:

```
extra1
extra2
```

I know that, because sed strips the newline from the end of each input line, the newline is not there to be matched - so that accounts for the result.  I have read articles on adding the next line from the buffer, but I can't work out what I need to use in the pattern match to get this to work.

The output I want is:

```
extra1
extra2
Yellow 5
```

(In case it makes a difference, I am using a Mac, so I need this to work with - I think - the FreeBSD variant of sed.)

Of course, if another tool is better for what I want to achieve I am open to suggestions!  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse (x)html with regular expressions. [Please don't do it.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/237955)

Comment: Actually I am not.  This is (partial) output from a process that decodes a binary plist and gives ASCII XML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match a string that contains a newline using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23850789/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the lines and tear them apart:

```
tr -d "\n" < file| grep -o "<string>[^<]*</string>"|sed 's/<string>\(.*\)<\/string>/\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you.  This does what I want - and, importantly, I understand it!

Comment: You can get the same effect by by setting `IFS` to **not** include the carriage return. Something like `IFStemp=$IFS; IFS=$' \t'; sed...; IFS=$IFStmp`

Comment: @SaxDaddy: Interesting! I tried `IFS=$' \t'; printf "%s\n%s\n" "first line" "second line" |  sed 's/line/part/'` but I just got two lines. What do I do wrong?

Comment: your first `\n` added a CR between the two lines. you probably want `printf "%s %s\n"`

Comment: @SaxDaddy I used the CR since the main issue is how to delete the CR between `<string>` and `</string>`.

Answer (score 3):

Close your array tag and try this with xmlstarlet and GNU sed:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//array/string" input.xml | sed '/ $/{:a;N;s/\n//;ta}'
```

Or only with xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t --match '//array/string' --value-of 'normalize-space()' -n input.xml
```

Output:

```
extra1
extra2
Yellow 5
```

Comment: I am not familiar with xmlstarlet, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you start talking about "buffers" or "hold space" or sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) you're simply using the wrong tool. All of that stuff for sed became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented so just use awk. Here's one way with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='</?string>' '!(NR%2){gsub(/\n/," "); print}' file
extra1
extra2
Yellow 5
```

The above just prints whatever's between `<string>` and `</string>` after converting any newlines to blank chars.

With other awks one way would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec " ") $0 }
END {
    split(rec,f,"</?string>")
    for (i=2;i in f;i+=2) {
        print f[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
extra1
extra2
Yellow 5
```

Comment: I take your point about the mid-1970s.  I'll have a better look at awk.

Comment: It will be well worth your while as we see a lot of people asking for sed answers and, unfortunately for them, getting them so it'd be good to know which sed constructs are still extremely useful and which are just a mental exercise/attempt to turn lead to gold! The book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins is your best starting point.

Comment: I will.  The biggest issue I have (apart from ignorance) is that I have too many ideas flowing at me (mostly from here) and insufficient time to do justice to researching them all properly!

Answer (score 1):

`perl` is available on OSX by default so you can use:

```
perl -0ne 's#<string>([^<]*)</string>#sub{$x=$1;$x=~tr/\n/ /;print $x."\n";}->()#eg' file.xml
extra1
extra2
Yellow 5
```

Alternatively you can install `gnu-awk` using `home brew` and use:

```
awk -v RS= -v FPAT='<string>([^<]*)</string>' 'for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
   gsub(/<\/?string>/, "", $i); gsub(/\n/, " ", $i); print $i}}' file.xml
extra1
extra2
Yellow 5
```

Comment: I'll look at perl as well as awk.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this problem with `xmllint`. I modified your example slightly so that you can see what's going on.

**test.xml**

```
<array>
  <string1>extra1</string1>
  <string2>extra2</string2>
  <string3>Yellow
5</string3>
</array>
```

Since you want the string with the line break, I made this value unique. Now use `xmllint` and `sed` to get your results

```
[saxdaddy ~]$  x="$(xmllint --xpath "/array/string3" test.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g')"
[saxdaddy ~]$  echo $x
Yellow 5
```

xmllint's `xpath` feature will search the XML in dictionary manner. `sed` will then strip our the beginning and ending tags. The "trick" to this is using quotes to capture the variable and then **not** using quotes to echo the result.

If your target tag is not unique in the file path, then you can craft a `for` loop to look for `$'\n'` (a line break) and set that to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a tool like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) that's designed to parse xml:

```
xidel -s input.xml -e '//string/normalize-space(.)'
extra1
extra2
Yellow 5
```