# What is the sed command to replace value from a file?

Tags: regex, sed

What is the sed command to replace a below line from a file.
I was using below sed command to replace a line, But it didn't work

```
sed -i 's/^fixed-address 135.250.187.128;\nfilename "vxrom.pxe.mg.latest";$/fixed-address 135.250.187.128;\nfilename "vxrom.pxe.mg/' dhcpd.txt
```

Input:

```
host sim127  {hardware ethernet 00:25:90:78:32:B4; fixed-address 135.250.187.127; filename "vxrom.pxe.mg.latest"; next-server 135.250.186.9; }
host sim128  {hardware ethernet 00:25:90:78:2E:FC; fixed-address 135.250.187.128; filename "vxrom.pxe.mg.latest"; next-server 135.250.186.9; }
```

Output:

```
host sim127  {hardware ethernet 00:25:90:78:32:B4; fixed-address 135.250.187.127; filename "vxrom.pxe.mg.8_0"; next-server 135.250.186.9; }
host sim128  {hardware ethernet 00:25:90:78:2E:FC; fixed-address 135.250.187.128; filename "vxrom.pxe.mg.latest"; next-server 135.250.186.9; }
```

Comment: you tagged the question with the answer: sed. or awk, or perl, or any other text processing language. "unix" doesn't do this thing. utilities that run under unix do.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? It looks like you want to make sure that `filename "vxrom.pxe.mg.latest"` is on the subsequent line after matching fixed-address 135.250.187.128. Try to articulate your requirements in plain english.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` operates on lines. But your expression includes the newline character `\n`. So you have to make `sed` use more than one line and aborting the evaluation at the newline, like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850894/1305969). So try using the prefix

> :a;N;$!ba;

in your `sed` expression before the `'s/.../.../g'`. I also replaced the `.` with its escaped sequence `\.` and appended a `g` so that all occurrences would be replaced. The result would look like this:

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/fixed-address\n135.250.187.128;\sfilename\s"vxrom.pxe.mg.latest";/fixed-address 135.250.187.128;\ filename "vxrom.pxe.mg";/g' dhcpd.txt
```

Comment: I have found one more solution here to resolve this issue . First we use grep command to get the line number of searching attribute from file #grep -n "<attribute-name>" <file-name> | cut -d ":" -f1 then we store the output of grep command in an attribute and increment the value of that attribute after that we use that attribute value in a sed command to substitute the value in a file.#sed -i '<attribute-name>s/<existing value>/<new value>'