# How can I replace multiple lines with sed

Tags: sed

I want to write a simple Markdown to LaTex converter and chose `sed` as the core component of the converter. It was suitable for everything until now when I hit the following problem: I want to convert a markdown code block (3 backticks) into a LaTex listing. The problem is that I want to work on multiple lines here. I tried the following command but it does not work since `sed` is processing the input line by line:

````
sed -E 's/```([[:print:]]*)```/\\begin{lstlisting}/1\\end{lstlisting}/g'
````

Another idea would be to try to only search and replace only the three backticks, but since every other occurrence needs to be replaced with `\end{lstlisting}` I do not know if it is possible. A hacky way would be to use three backticks for the start of the code block and four for the end, but that is quite a dirty solution in my opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match a string that contains a newline using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850789/match-a-string-that-contains-a-newline-using-sed)

Comment: Firstly, that question has been asked many times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850789 to name two. Secondly, unless this is something you intend to throw away after use, I'd direct you to writing a proper parser (or using an existing one as a library): tokenization, AST tree, etc. Lastly, I believe `pandoc` does most of what you seem to want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

````
sed -E '/^```/{:a;N;/\n```$/!ba
        s/^```(.*)```$/\\begin{lstlisting}\1\\end{lstlisting}/}' file
````

On encountering ```` ``` ```` at the beginning of a line, gather up all lines untill another such line and replace those lines by `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}`.